# One PSU powering one high power device & one low power device

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, basic, circuit-protection

If one was to power a (potentially) multi-amp device and an arduino with an external LM7812 12v voltage regulator to a 19v laptop charger (in parallel), would the arduino be safe when the multi-amp device started pulling lots of current?

[image]

Comment: The amount of current pulled by individual modules does not affect the Arduino providing the voltage rail stays stable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to this example:

The water tower in my town can supply 76 households simultaneously. If 40 households has their shower running, will I, number 41, also get water when I take my shower? Or is the water tower unable to give me water?

---

Extra information:

- \$19.5V×3.9A=76W\$
- \$5V×2A=10W\$
- \$4\$ buck converters => \$40 W\$

---

Yes, they will take their showers, you are not going to take their water, nor will they take your water.

You could even attach 3 buck converters more and have 6 W to spare for the Arduino nano. The Arduino nano will not consume 6 W, it will take what it needs. The remaining W that is not taken stays at the water tower, it stays in the electrical grid.

Answer (score 1):

That configuration will work in principle - assuming, of course, that the power required by the loads doesn't exceed the power available from the power supply. That condition is fulfilled by the diagram as shown currently. However changes to the configuration (e.g. adding more buck regulator + charger combinations etc.) could invalidate that.

It's common for a piece of equipment to have one (high current) power supply, and then multiple loads (in your case, those are the Arduino and the four buck regulator + charger combinations). Each load draws only the current that it requires.

Three points to which I would pay special attention:

- In case buck regulator + charger loads switch on/off while the Arduino is running, causing (up to) a ~0.5A load transient on the 19V power supply each time, ensure you have the recommended capacitors on the 7812 regulator input & output, physically close to the regulator.
- If you are getting that 19V laptop power supply from Ebay or similar, beware that many such power supplies cannot actually provide their quoted (rated)  current.
- If you are getting the buck regulators from Ebay or similar, beware (again) that some have "optimistic" specifications e.g. they may quote a maximum output current that can only be supplied with a very small input/output voltage differential.

  In your case, the buck regulators have 19V input and 5V output. Even if those voltages are within the quoted specifications for your chosen buck regulator, that does not mean that the full quoted output current is available in such a configuration. You will need to carry out your own tests for suitability.